# A milder version of strenuous

Tags: synonyms

Is there a word that works as a milder version of *strenuous*? *Strenuous* is defined by [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/strenuous) as something "requiring or using great effort or exertion." I'm looking for a word with a similar definition except for the "great" part.

Comment: I might say "taxing".

Answer (score 2):

**[diligent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diligent)**:

> characterized by steady, earnest, and energetic effort

Comment: Interesting cultural difference. As an Australian I would never use diligent in this sense, but rather in the sense provided by ODO's definition: "Having or showing care and conscientiousness in one’s work or duties: *after diligent searching, he found a parcel*". http://www.dictionary.com/browse/diligent shows that there is indeed a distinction between the U.S. and British usages. Fascinating!!

Comment: So for an answer **within a U.S. context**, +1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to define the degree of effort implied by a lot of these words, but you could try something like *tiring*:

Definition & Example (via Merriam Webster):

> causing weariness, restlessness, or lack of interest
>
> the seminar was tiring and not particularly helpful or informative

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [***difficult***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/difficult) will do:

> Needing much effort or skill to accomplish, deal with, or understand:
> *'she had a difficult decision to make'
>
> 'the questions are too difficult for the children'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/difficult

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *taxing*:

> Physically or mentally demanding.

Or even *laborious*:

> (Especially of a task, process, or journey) requiring considerable effort and time.